# OGR: How to save layer from AttributeFilter to a shapefile?

Tags: python, ogr, select-by-attribute

I select a subset of features from my shapefile like so:

```
node_lyr = nodes.GetLayer()
q_str = "%s = %i" % (field, value)
node_lyr.SetAttributeFilter(q_str)
```

What is the best way to make a shapefile from this subset?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the [ogr.DataSource.CopyLayer](http://www.gdal.org/ogr/classOGRDataSource.html#a42dc7f7f538cd4f083af350722fe53ae) method.

For example:

```
from osgeo import ogr
inds = ogr.Open('test1.shp')
inlyr=inds.GetLayer()
inlyr.SetAttributeFilter('NAME = "a"')
drv = ogr.GetDriverByName( 'ESRI Shapefile' )
outds = drv.CreateDataSource( "test2.shp" )
outlyr = outds.CopyLayer(inlyr,'test2')
del inlyr,inds,outlyr,outds
```

Comment: Perfect, this is what I was looking for. Thanks mate.

Comment: I've read the same article and was surprised to find the lock on the layer even after calling `del layer`.