# I have a shapefile where in I want to select features based on their feature ids

Tags: python, query

I have a list of feature ids and I am using layer.SetAttributeFilter for that but the code neither selects those features nor does it raise an error. I took help from these questions:

[OGR Filter Vector Layer by a List of Feature ID's](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/270708/ogr-filter-vector-layer-by-a-list-of-feature-ids)

[OGR: How to save layer from AttributeFilter to a shapefile?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/68650/ogr-how-to-save-layer-from-attributefilter-to-a-shapefile)

Here is my code:

```
inlyr=inds.GetLayer()
m =[]
for a in range (0, len(new_coords1)):
    m.append(new_coords1[a])
inlyr.SetAttributeFilter("POINTID IN {}".format(tuple(m)))
drv = ogr.GetDriverByName( 'ESRI Shapefile' )
outds = drv.CreateDataSource( "test2.shp" )
outlyr = outds.CopyLayer(inlyr,'test2')
del inlyr,inds,outlyr,outds
```

where POINTID is the name of the id field. The output creates a new shapefile with all the features and not the selected features. I also tried executing the SetAttributeFilter separately which gives an output of 5. I don't know what that output means.

Comment: I would try to convert the tuple(m) to a comma separated string, for SetAttributeFilter. If Pointid is a string field, you probably need to quote the values.

Comment: i tried that but the output remains the same @klewis. The code was this:                                 `m = tuple(m)
str_join = ",".join(str(x) for x in m)
inlyr.SetAttributeFilter("POINTID IN {}".format(str_join)) `

Comment: Also the POINTID is an int field.So didn't quote the values.

Comment: I think IN operator needs its own parenthesis, "POINTID IN ({})", like this POINTID IN (1,2,3)

Comment: I tried that as well .. but there is no change in the output.@klewis.